# How to prevent docker build from redownloading copied Go vendor

Tags: docker, go, caching

I'm trying to make `Dockerfile` runs faster by copying whole directory (including `vendor`, because redownloading dependencies took about 10m+ where I live), but when I tried to run it, it always redownload vendor again and again, unlike when `go mod vendor` in local:

```
FROM golang:1.14-alpine AS builder
RUN apk --update add ca-certificates git make g++
ENV GO111MODULE=on

WORKDIR /app

RUN go get github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv

COPY . .

RUN go mod vendor

ARG COMMIT_HASH
ENV COMMIT_HASH=${COMMIT_HASH}
ARG BUILD_DATE
ENV BUILD_DATE=${BUILD_DATE}

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 \
    go build \
    -o app

FROM golang:1.14-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
COPY --from=builder /go/bin/dlv /
COPY --from=builder /app/app .
COPY --from=builder /app/db ./db
EXPOSE 8080 63342
CMD [ "/dlv", "--listen=:63342", "--headless=true", "--api-version=2", "--accept-multiclient", "exec", "./app" ]
```

previously using this (without vendor) also slow:

```
COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .
RUN go mod download -x
COPY . .
```

trying with this also didn't work:

```
COPY vendor /go/pkg/mod
COPY vendor /go/pkg/mod/cache/download
COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .

RUN go mod download -x

COPY . .
```

how to force it to use copied vendor directory instead of redownloading again and again?

so the expected behavior are:

1. when local have `vendor` (used `go mod vendor`), the `docker build` should use it
2. but when on CI (since `vendor/*/*` not committed to the repo) or developer that doesn't have `vendor/*/*` it should probably redownload everything (I don't really care, since they have good bandwidth)

the `go mod vendor` command is for the CI and devs that haven't use `go mod vendor`

Comment: Can't you just mount `${GOPATH}/pkg/mod` and allow artifacts to accumulate on your runner? Vendoring feels like a step backwards.

Comment: how's that? @Zyl you mean the docker-compose? it doesn't work for multi-stage build

Comment: If "COPY go.mod .; COPY go.sum .; RUN go mod download -x" is slow, then your docker image layer cache isn't being hit. It won't even execute the 'go mod download' if the layer already exists.

Comment: yup, what i think about `step backward` is redownloading whole dependency, even when it's only partially changed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`go mod vendor` only downloads dependencies from the network if the dependency isn't ready in your local environment. Otherwise, it'll just copy the dependency to the folder `vendor` without accessing the network. Your issue comes from the `go mod cache` not being reused during multiple builds.

As a solution, you could use [buildkit cache solution](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/syntax.md#example-cache-go-packages).

A minimal example:

**main.go:**

```
package main

import _ "github.com/jeanphorn/log4go"

func main() {
}
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1.3
FROM golang:1.14-alpine AS builder

RUN apk --update add git

ENV GO111MODULE=on
WORKDIR /app

COPY main.go /app

RUN go mod init hello

RUN --mount=type=cache,mode=0755,target=/go/pkg/mod go get github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv && go get github.com/jeanphorn/log4go
RUN --mount=type=cache,mode=0755,target=/go/pkg/mod go mod vendor
```

**1st Execution:**

```
$ export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
$ docker build --progress=plain -t abc:1 . --no-cache
#16 [builder 6/7] RUN --mount=type=cache,mode=0755,target=/go/pkg/mod go get github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv && go get github.com/jeanphorn/log4go
#16 sha256:ae394bc67787799808175eada48c5f4e09101b6e153d535ddb5e4040fbf74395
#16 1.941 go: downloading github.com/go-delve/delve v1.7.1
#16 4.296 go: found github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv in github.com/go-delve/delve v1.7.1
......
#16 23.78 go: finding module for package github.com/toolkits/file
#16 23.96 go: downloading github.com/toolkits/file v0.0.0-20160325033739-a5b3c5147e07
#16 24.17 go: found github.com/toolkits/file in github.com/toolkits/file v0.0.0-20160325033739-a5b3c5147e07
#16 DONE 27.3s
```

**2nd Execution:**

```
$ export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
$ docker build --progress=plain -t abc:1 . --no-cache
#15 [builder 6/7] RUN --mount=type=cache,mode=0755,target=/go/pkg/mod go get github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv && go get github.com/jeanphorn/log4go
#15 sha256:bee74f92ceb79cce449b9702c892cb39815461981838f6b63d500414be87c21d
#15 1.467 go: found github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv in github.com/go-delve/delve v1.7.1
#15 7.511 go: github.com/jeanphorn/log4go upgrade => v0.0.0-20190526082429-7dbb8deb9468
#15 7.533 go: finding module for package github.com/toolkits/file
#15 7.675 go: found github.com/toolkits/file in github.com/toolkits/file v0.0.0-20160325033739-a5b3c5147e07
#15 DONE 8.7s
```

You could see `golang mod cache` generated by the 1st run already being reused by 2nd run without downloading from the internet. Now it works the same as when you do it on host.

NOTE: I didn't suggest to directly bind any cache on host to container. It's not portable, I think.

Comment: eh wait, but this won't work on CI right?

Comment: oh nevermind :3
`BuildKit has been integrated to docker build since Docker 18.06 .`

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, got answer from [@zasdaym](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15905159/zasda-yusuf-mikail)

```
COPY go.mod go.sum source.go
COPY vendor ./vendor

RUN go build -mod vendor -o out.exe
```

it would not redownload